# How can I insert data into the SQLITE database with a foreign key using a content values?

Tags: android, content-values

I have a table below:

```
+=================+
+ CATEGORY_TABLE  +
+=================+
+ PK | owner_id   +
+ FK | task_id    +
+    | lastname   +
+    | firstname  +
+    | etc...     +
+=================+

+=================+
+   TASK_TABLE    +
+=================+
+ PK | task_id    +
+ FK | task_title +
+=================+
```

What I want to know is how can I insert data into my **Owner** table and put as well the `task_id` FK from my `TASK_TABLE`? This is using contentvalues.

Please check my snippet code below:

```
    //insert data to account table
public  boolean insert_account(String acc_uname, String acc_email, String acc_passw, String acc_type, String acc_status){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("acc_uname", acc_uname);
    contentValues.put("acc_email", acc_email);
    contentValues.put("acc_passw", acc_passw);
    contentValues.put("acc_type", acc_type);
    contentValues.put("acc_status", acc_status);

    long insert = db.insert("ACCOUNT", null, contentValues);
    if(insert==1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Typically, you would insert into your TASK_TABLE first.  Your task_id is probably an autoincrementing value assigned by the database.  Then, you query SQLite again to get the last_insert_id by running the SQL Query select last_insert_rowid() against the same SQLite database.  Then, you would run your insert into the CATEGORY_TABLE using the value you received from the last_insert_rowid() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use triggers in sqlite

An SQLite trigger is a named database object that is executed automatically when an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement is issued against the associated table.

check out this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_triggers.htm) to learn more about triggers

Comment: Thank you for that. Sorry I am a beginner in android. Should I not add something in my `insert_account` method?

Comment: no, after adding the trigger it should automatically apply what your trigger does, check out the examples in the link above

Comment: Thanks for you help :)